# VoIP Wireshark analysis, can see RTP stream but couldn't found SIP or H323

Tags: sip, voip, wireshark, stun

Forgive me if I'am asking the wrong question. Recently I am trying to analyze some voip traffic in Wireshark. But all I could see are small UDP packets; some containing RTP streams and I can see various codec information like G.711, G.723 etc. But there is no sign of SIP or any other signaling packets. Is it possible to hide SIP or H323 signalling within UDP packets in a way which are undetectable to Wireshark? or STUN can do some encoding to hide signalling packets?

Answer (score 0):

No. By default Wireshark captures SIP in standard ports, and you probably are using some other port.

You can to `Edit > Preferences... > Protocols > SIP` and check the ports that are being used to identify SIP traffic.

Another way to force it to parse the packets as SIP, is to create a filter by the protocol and port being used (e.g. udp.port == 5060 || tcp.port == 5060) and then select a packet, and go to `Analyze > Decode as... > Transport > SIP`.

Answer (score 0):

Wanted to share similar experience.

Wireshark was not showing some SIP packets. I was very sure these packets were sent. I discovered something unusual with wireshark displays. It will group many packets within a single packet. This is typical if you have busy traffic. You to check each packet

Answer (score 0):

Wireshark SIP Protocol [Analysis](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=91FNtE2mY2g),Replaying Captured VoIP Calls,Playing VoIP calls, use your filter to filer the SIP and RTP protocol, if the column is missing  go to edit->Preferences->Select Column->Add column Protocol

Answer (score 0):

Yes. "But there is no sign of SIP or any other signaling packets." You can encode number inside RTP packets (RTP events) using DTMF. Then SIP is only used in initial authorization, then you only use DTMF in RTP, see RFC 2833. Also there is an option to encode DTMF in Audio (in-band), but this is not "standard". SIP Info packet (third method) should be the preferred method though.